# Parameter passing between .NET and PLSQL

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, odp.net

I'm trying to pass a table of numbers to my procedure from my .NET Code. The type of the parameter is the following :

> TYPE ARRAY_OF_NUMBER AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

I'm calling the procedure with the following code :

> ```
>             OracleParameter x = new OracleParameter();
>             x.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal;
>             x.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
>             x.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
>             x.Value = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
>             objCmd.Parameters.Add(x);
> ```

But I get the following error, due to the format of x.Value :

> PLS-00306: numéro ou types d'arguments erronés

Do you have any idea of the .NET type that could fit with a "TABLE OF NUMBER" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an associative array, for example:

```
TYPE ARRAY_OF_NUMBER AS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY INTEGER;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have probably mistaken, the `TYPE` is not `ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY`. It is a `NESTED TABLE`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an associative array ? http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/associative-arrays-9i.php

Comment: @TD Lemon, are you sure you understand `NESTED TABLE` and an `ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY`? Do you see `INDEX BY` in the type declaration?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a PL/SQL table to me rather than a nested table.

If you are using a nested table, that is a User Defined Type, and you should use the Oracle Developer Tools Custom class generation tool to create a .NET class you can map to it.

For better performance, use an associative array instead when possible.

Walk through for the custom class generator:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:4267364986371:::24:P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PROD_SECTION_GRP_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:10199,,24